# Accessing the committer's name as a Jenkinsfile environment variable

Tags: jenkins, jenkinsfile, environment-variables

Using the `env.BRANCH_NAME` variable accessible in the Jenkinsfile outside of the `pipeline{}` block, I have set up a variable used to conditionally set the node used to build the git branch. I would like to also access the name of the developer who committed the change, but I do not know how to access it.

I need a variable assigned before the pipeline block to assign to `pipeline { agent { label selected_agent }}`. If I attempt to use a method call instead of a variable there, the Java parser complains:

> java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.agent.impl.Label.label
>   expects class java.lang.String but received class
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ClosureModelTranslator

I cannot run code inside the pipeline block before the agent block to define the variable, and the agent block has to be the first part of the pipeline declaration.

If I could run bash commands, I could access the author's name, and in fact I do use it at the end of the Jenkinsfile to pull the git committer's name for the status email, but if I attempt to use sh() before the pipeline block I get this error:

```
Required context class hudson.FilePath is missing
Perhaps you forgot to surround the code with a step that provides this, such as: node
```

I am not sure what else to try. Does anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to ask in your question, so I'm answering the question I believe you're trying to ask.

A build does not necessarily have a single commit author.  It has a list of committers, which can be empty or can contain many committers.  To create this list, you can use this snippet in a scripted Pipeline (note that you may need to disable the sandbox in order to use `.collect()`):

```
changeAuthors = currentBuild.changeSets.collect { set ->
  set.collect { entry -> entry.author.fullName }
}.flatten()
```

I use this with Git as my SCM; I'm not sure if it works with other SCMs.

See also the following questions on StackOverflow (some answers may be outdated):

- [How to get culprits or committers inside a Jenkins workflow with one or more SCMs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30398465/how-to-get-culprits-or-committers-inside-a-jenkins-workflow-with-one-or-more-scm)
- [How do you pull git committer information for Jenkins pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37755586/how-do-you-pull-git-committer-information-for-jenkins-pipeline)